# What technology should I use to create question / answer website?

Tags: web-apps, database, web-browser, data-visualization, web-server

**Quick description:**
The goal is to create website that would quickly answer most popular law-related questions. User would go to the page, type in a question and receive an answer with legal argumentation. All answers would be pre-entered by a team of lawyers, no user interaction will be required.

**Requirements:**

- possibility to search a question in a database (many possible ways of
  asking about the same thing!)
- possibility to easily edit questions and answers by system administrator
- visually simple and readable design
- every question should have two 'text sections' assigned: legal explanation, and code paragraphs to justify it.
- no user input

what software / technology should be used to implement the search bar?

Answer (score 1):

What about StackExchange? Do you know there's a StackExchange site for Law questions? Here:

http://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a clearly technical question and not a law-based question. It's good to know though...

Answer (score 0):

You can choose your technologies from [this elaborate list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site) of Open source, Not open source, Ones that look sort of finished and Others that seem to be work in progress. They're also categorised separately by technologies your preferred technology.

[Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site)